# outline definition of sub class constructor using base class constructor

Tags: c++

I want to define a constructor for a subclass using it's base class but not using the initializer list.
I mean why I can not  use base class constructor in sub class constructor but out of the sub class scope.

```cpp
class base
{
public:
    base(int _x);

protected:
    int x;
};

base::base(int _x)
{
    x = _x;
}

class sub : public base
{
public:
    sub(int _x, int _r);

private:
    int r;
};

sub::sub(int _x, int _r)
{
    base(_x); // here I got syntax error
    r = _r;
}
```

I know that I can use initialize list like this :

```
sub(int _x, int _r) : base(_x), r(_r) {};
```

but I want to know why using the first code above is wrong and I get syntax error 
as I mentioned.

Comment: The only solution is to define a default constructor `base()` and a method (e.g. `void base::setX(int)` which can be used in body of `sub::sub()`. Why you cannot use the construction exposed in your last snippet?

Comment: Because you can't run base class constructor from anywhere else than initializer list. That is how C++ was designed.

Comment: what you want is not c++, this is Java syntax...

Comment: In addition to @Fureeish: The construction of base class and members is well defined (base class first, then exact order of member variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
sub::sub(int _x, int _r)
{
   // Too late...
}
```

As soon as you enter the `sub` constructor body, your `base` class has to be constructed.

Because you didn't specify any constructor in the initializer list, the compiler tries to call the default constructor, but `base` has none.

This is why you get the `no matching function for call to 'base::base()'` error.

You can do this instead:

```
sub::sub(int _x, int _r) : base(_x)
{
 r = _r;
}
```

There is no need to call the default constructor anymore, so it works.

Plus, you shouldn't try to call constructor by hand.

This:

```
 base(_x); // here I got syntax error
```

Actually creates a temporary `base` object, it doesn't call the current object constructor.